# MarkLogic How to insert document in specify forest

Tags: marklogic

I have duplicate URIs in my database. I want test by replicating the issue with the same URI in different forests of my `test-dup` database, but
it spools out errors. Looks like I am unable to assign URI in forest.

> 1.0-ml] XDMP-PLACEKEYSLOCKING: xdmp:document-insert("/xquery/catalog.xml", 557........., (), (), 0, (xs:unsignedLong("13222250964842568399"), xs:unsignedLong("15490631252765310070"))) -- Fast locking cannot be used with place keys.

```
xquery version "1.0-ml";
let $XML:=<catalog>
             <product dept="WMN">
             <number>557</number>
             <name language="en">Fleece Pullover</name>
             <colorChoices>navy black</colorChoices>
</product>
let $filename:= "/xquery/catalog.xml"
return
xdmp:document-insert($filename,$XML,(),(),0,xdmp:database-forests(xdmp:database("test-dup")) )
```

Answer (score 0):

Is your database **timestamp** set to "fast"?

> In order to load a document into a forest by explicitly specifying a forest key, the forest must exist and be attached to the database into which you are loading. Attempting to load a document into a forest that does not belong to the context database will throw an exception. **Additionally, the locking parameter must be set to strict on the database configuration, otherwise an XDMP-PLACEKEYSLOCKING exception is thrown.**

If you change it to `strict` then you won't see the error, but still won't get duplicates.

An easy way to replicate the duplicate document issue is to:

1. ensure that the rebalancer is disabled
2. detach one of the **test-dup** forests (i.e. test-dup1)
3. insert your document
4. detach the forest it was inserted into (i.e. test-dup2)
5. re-attach the test-dup1 forest
6. insert the document again
7. attach both test-dup1 and test-dup2 forests

You will now have duplicate documents for the same URI, as it will live in both test-dup1 and test-dup2 forests.